# Vec::dedup does not work — how do I filter duplicates from vector of chars?

Tags: rust

I need to filter out duplicates from a `Vec<char>` which is the result of merging two `vectors`. I'm using the `dedup` method, however it only removes duplicates from the origin parts and neighborhood elements.
E.g:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = "abccdddd".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let mut b = "dadddefacd".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    a.append(&mut b);
    a.dedup();
    println!("{:?}", a)
}
```

Expected: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`
Got: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'd']`

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=cc06d9fd15e48de591f5827263ad9388))

How can I delete the duplicates from the merged vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for [`Vec::dedup`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup)

> Removes **consecutive** repeated elements in the vector.
>   If the vector is sorted, this removes all duplicates.

You have to sort the vector first, then dedup it.

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = "abccdddd".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let mut b = "addddefacd".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    a.append(&mut b);
    a.sort();
    a.dedup();
    println!("{:?}", a)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answer by hellow it is also possible to deduplicate a vector without sorting it by using a `HashSet`:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut a = "zabccdddd".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let mut b = "dadddefacdz".chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    a.append(&mut b);

    let mut uniques = HashSet::new();
    a.retain(|e| uniques.insert(e.clone()));

    println!("{:?}", a) // ['z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
}
```

[`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) preserves the elements fulfilling the predicate and [`HashSet::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.insert) returns `true` if the inserted element is not present in the set. Since a `HashSet` can only have unique members, this makes the vector only keep the first occurences of its repeated elements.

Comment: This solution retains the order of the original vector, which is sometimes a desirable property. If you don't care about the order, I'd recommend using a `HashSet` instead of a `Vec` from the outset.